# Generating random email addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

The code below generates **only** 10 email domains. To me, this is bruteforce programming. Is there another random integer library? Could I use something like `random.seed()` in C++?

What is a more elegant way to generate 100 emails names using some Python libs/APIs?

```
import random
domains = [ "hotmail.com", "gmail.com", "aol.com", "mail.com" , "mail.kz", "yahoo.com"]
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d","e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]

def get_one_random_domain(domains):
        return domains[random.randint( 0, len(domains)-1)]


def get_one_random_name(letters):
    email_name = ""
    for i in range(7):
        email_name = email_name + letters[random.randint(0,11)]
    return email_name

def generate_random_emails():

    for i in range(0,10):
         one_name = str(get_one_random_name(letters))
         one_domain = str(get_one_random_domain(domains))         
         print(one_name  + "@" + one_domain)

def main():                
    generate_random_emails()
```

In `get_one_random_name()`, how can I make this `email_name` string grow with random letters without using "+ "?

How can I choose letters randomly and put them together without +?

Comment: This question still doesn't make sense; if anything, it's a worse fit here than SO. What exactly is the problem with the standard library `random` module? It has a `seed` function, although it's not clear what you'd use it for.

Comment: By the way, if you're going to be using these in examples or anything where people might misinterpret them as legitimate email addresses, you might want to use only the domain `example.com`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python) :

```
import random

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print(random.choice(foo))
```

In your case,

```
def get_one_random_domain(domains):
        return domains[random.randint( 0, len(domains)-1)]
```

becomes :

```
def get_one_random_domain(domains):
        return random.choice(domains)
```

and maybe removes the need for a function in the first place.

---

Your `letters` list can easily be defined with a list comprehension and some manipulation of `ord` and `chr` :

```
>>> [chr(ord('a')+i) for i in range(12)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
```

As suggested in the comments, you can also use `string.ascii_lowercase[:12]`

---

Now, your `get_one_random_name` could be easily improved.

```
def get_one_random_name(letters):
    email_name = ""
    for i in range(7):
        email_name = email_name + letters[random.randint(0,11)]
    return email_name
```

using the previous trick, it becomes :

```
def get_one_random_name(letters):
    email_name = ""
    for i in range(7):
        email_name = email_name + random.choice(letters)
    return email_name
```

Also, here is a recommandation from [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) :

> For example, do not rely on CPython's efficient implementation of
>   in-place string concatenation for statements in the form a += b or a =
>   a + b. This optimization is fragile even in CPython (it only works for
>   some types) and isn't present at all in implementations that don't use
>   refcounting. In performance sensitive parts of the library, the
>   ''.join() form should be used instead. This will ensure that
>   concatenation occurs in linear time across various implementations.

In your case, you can easily build a list of random letters and call join.

```
def get_one_random_name(letters):
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(7))
```

---

In `generate_random_emails` :

- you don't need conversions.
- you don't need temporary variables
- you don't need the first argument of `range` if it is 0.

so you get:

```
def generate_random_emails():
    for i in range(0,10):
         print(get_one_random_name(letters) + '@' + get_one_random_domain(domains))
```

Also, it might be a good idea to return a list instead of printing values to make code easier to reuse.

---

At this stage, the code looks like :

```
import random
domains = [ "hotmail.com", "gmail.com", "aol.com", "mail.com" , "mail.kz", "yahoo.com"]
letters = string.ascii_lowercase[:12] 

def get_one_random_domain(domains):
    return random.choice(domains)

def get_one_random_name(letters):
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(7))

def generate_random_emails():
    return [get_one_random_name(letters) + '@' + get_one_random_domain(domains) for i in range(10)]

def main():                
    print(generate_random_emails())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A good idea would be to change the function names and add arguments instead of hard coded values :

```
import random
domains = [ "hotmail.com", "gmail.com", "aol.com", "mail.com" , "mail.kz", "yahoo.com"]
letters = string.ascii_lowercase[:12]

def get_random_domain(domains):
    return random.choice(domains)

def get_random_name(letters, length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

def generate_random_emails(nb, length):
    return [get_random_name(letters, length) + '@' + get_random_domain(domains) for i in range(nb)]

def main():
    print(generate_random_emails(10, 7))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: amazing, this codereview site is better than stackoverflow

Comment: For `letters`, use `string.ascii_lowercase[:12]`.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my answer to take into account your comment. I've learnt something today :)

Comment: @Josay, how does this last line "get_random_domain(domains) for i in range() ] work? how does python allow for loop go in  the end?

Comment: just a note: `string` is missing in the import statement